# Use independent injected services in durable activity function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a orchestrator function

This takes data which is split by client

```
[FunctionName(nameof(ProcessDataWithDurableFunctions))]
 public  async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] 
     IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
 {
     
     dataSplitByClient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, ProcessClientData>>(json);
 
     var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
     foreach (var item in dataSplitByClient)
     {
         tasks.Add(ProcessClientWithContextAsync(context, item.Value));
     }

     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
     
     var outputs = tasks.Select(x => x.Result).ToList();
     return outputs;
 }

 private Task<string> ProcessClientWithContextAsync(IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ProcessClientData item)
    {
        context.SetCustomStatus(new
        {
            item.ClientName,
            item.ClientId, 
            TotalItemsToProcess = item.Data.Count
        });

        _tmService.Identifier = item.ClientName;

        var result = context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(ProcessClientData), item);
        return result;
    }
```

I want to process data for each client using an activity function ProcessClientData

```
    [FunctionName(nameof(ProcessClientData))]
    public async Task<string> ProcessClientData([ActivityTrigger] ProcessClientData clientToProcessDataFor, 
        ILogger logger)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var logText = $"Processing Data for {clientToProcessDataFor.ClientName} with {clientToProcessDataFor.Data.Count} events";
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(logText);
        logger.LogInformation(logText);

        logger.LogInformation(_myService.Identifier);

        logText = $"Finished Processing Data for {clientToProcessDataFor.ClientName} with {clientToProcessDataFor.Data.Count} events";
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(logText);
        logger.LogInformation(logText);

        var result = stringBuilder.ToString().RemoveTrailingCrlf();
        return result;
    }
```

This is where I hit a big issue.

I need each activity function instance to have its own instance of DataProcessorService which is a transient service containing an efcore DbContext

This whole architecture wont work in its current form because it is never possible to run operations in parallel within a DbContext

I would be running activity functions in parallel so I will get concurrent issues

Ideally I would be able to inject IDataProcessorService into the activity function but annoyingly this is not supported

How can I get round this major issue?

Paul